# Clever (?) trick to avoid heap fragmentation

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, heap-memory

I work with image processing in C++ and sometimes get into memory problems because of heap fragmentation (at least I think fragmentation is the problem)

Lets say the image class looks like this (pseudo code)

```
    Image::Image(fileList): // ImageStack constructor
      nextStackMember_(NULL), 
      fileName_(""),
      intVar1_(0),
//
//
      intVar10_(0);
      bitmap_(NULL)
{
  // Code to initialize all attributes except bitmap_
  // bitmap_ is created from fileName when actually needed
}
```

There are member methods to dump and to load bitmap_
If the constructor initialized bitmap_ of all members at creation I would get a heap built up like this: .---.------.--.----------.-- and so on
"." is tiny heap space taken by attributes,"---" is large heap space taken up by bitmaps.
If the stack contains - say - 1000 images it can use all available heap.
If so dumping a bitmap_ might not let the program make a new image because all loaded images might be smaller.
Even if I before constructing the new image I dump ALL loaded images (by emptying their bitmap_ the heap will be totally fragmented.

Now to the "Clever" part: by only loading bitmap_s after every image in the stack is created I should get a heap that looks like this:
......…..-------------------------------------
this way all other attributes will be snugly fit together in the heap and I could easily create heap areas that are big enough for whatever sized new image I want to create.

This doesnt seem to work as I hoped.
What did I do wrong or am I completely on the wrong road?

edit: is there some possibility in visualC to get a visualization of the heap of a running program?

Comment: If it didn't help, it may be that memory fragmentation isn't the problem.

Comment: I think you need to look at how the common implementations of malloc work. The trick you describe should be unnecessary.

Comment: If the second solution works, then you don't seem to be deleting and recreating instances a lot at runtime (you know how many you will need) so I doubt you ever experienced fragmentation in the first place. You may be thinking of memory locality?